# Why does my collection change according to where I declare a variable in a recursive procedure?

Tags: c#

In the code below, the StylusPointCollection (SPC) changes according to whether I declare the StylusPoint variable inside or outside the method (i.e. if I comment the internal definition and uncomment the commented lines) .  I don't understand why this is.

```
//StylusPoint spXY;

private void DrawBinaryTree(int depth, StylusPoint pt, double length, double theta)
{        
    if (depth > 0)
    {    
        StylusPoint spXY = new StylusPoint(pt.X + length * Math.Cos(theta) * Math.Cos(a), pt.Y + length * Math.Sin(theta) * Math.Sin(a));

        //spXY = new StylusPoint(pt.X + length * Math.Cos(theta) * Math.Cos(a), pt.Y + length * Math.Sin(theta) * Math.Sin(a));

        SPC.Add(pt);
        SPC.Add(spXY);

        DrawBinaryTree(depth - 1, spXY, length * lengthScale, theta + deltaTheta);
        DrawBinaryTree(depth - 1, spXY, length * lengthScale, theta - deltaTheta);
    }
}
```

I have tried and failed to come up with a more simple example using LinqPad.

Comment: So your not going to tell us HOW is changed, or what the problem is?

Comment: Changes how?  This is very vague.

Comment: yeah, I've been struggling with that, the image is different (wrong) when displayed on a canvas using the variable when it is declared outside the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference stems from the fact that you make two recursive calls to the function trying to pass the variable in question to both.  When you declare the variable outside the function, it gets modified by each call to `DrawBinaryTree`.  When you declare the variable local, each call to `DrawBinaryTree` gets its own copy of the variable that other calls cannot modify

With a local:

```
private void DrawBinaryTree(int depth, StylusPoint pt, double length, double theta)
{        
    if (depth > 0)
    {    
        StylusPoint spXY = new StylusPoint(pt.X + length * Math.Cos(theta) * Math.Cos(a), pt.Y + length * Math.Sin(theta) * Math.Sin(a));

        SPC.Add(pt);
        SPC.Add(spXY);

        //spXY has the values you just set above 
        DrawBinaryTree(depth - 1, spXY, length * lengthScale, theta + deltaTheta);
        //since spXY is local, it still has the values you set above in this
        //call to the function (recursive calls have not modified it)
        DrawBinaryTree(depth - 1, spXY, length * lengthScale, theta - deltaTheta);
    }
}
```

With a global:

```
StylusPoint spXY;

private void DrawBinaryTree(int depth, StylusPoint pt, double length, double theta)
{        
    if (depth > 0)
    {    
        spXY = new StylusPoint(pt.X + length * Math.Cos(theta) * Math.Cos(a), pt.Y + length * Math.Sin(theta) * Math.Sin(a));

        SPC.Add(pt);
        SPC.Add(spXY);

        //spXY has the values you just set above 
        //(assuming there are no other functions running on other threads that modify it)
        DrawBinaryTree(depth - 1, spXY, length * lengthScale, theta + deltaTheta);
        //spXY now has the values from the last recursive call to DrawBinaryTree!
        DrawBinaryTree(depth - 1, spXY, length * lengthScale, theta - deltaTheta);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be right to say that this is a form of 'capture' in relation to the variable?

Comment: @descf No, it would not.  It's simply a matter of variables existing at different scopes.  In one case there is one shared variable, in the other there are several non-shared variables.